# I am using MKMapview with mk annotation. My app is crashing. Crash occurred at MKAnnotationContainerView

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview

My requirement is, track the user location and draw line with multiple colors in the map view. I am using Craig's Code from [this link](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=108). I am adding annotations on his route two times:

1. When ever user's location changed (Here I am adding CSMapAnnotationTypeEnd). Remove the old annotation and then I am adding new one.
2. Whenever user double taps the screen(Here I am adding CSMapAnnotationTypeImage).

And map view is blinking, whenever new location found. I don't need this blinking.

But my app is crashing, here is the crash report.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x310ebf4e __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b4c46aa objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x310eba4c __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
3   MapKit                          0x32284dfe -[MKAnnotationContainerView _updateAnnotationViewPerspective] + 238
4   MapKit                          0x32284c3c -[MKNewAnnotationContainerView _updateAnnotationViewPerspective] + 56
5   MapKit                          0x322b6962 -[MKMapView annotationManager:didAddAnnotationRepresentations:] + 42
6   MapKit                          0x32280bc4 -[MKAnnotationManager updateVisibleAnnotations] + 1196
7   Foundation                      0x31acfec8 __NSFireTimer + 60
8   CoreFoundation                  0x310b70e2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
9   CoreFoundation                  0x310b6cfa __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 778
10  CoreFoundation                  0x310b5096 __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3101fce2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3101fac6 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
13  GraphicsServices                0x35d4027e GSEventRunModal + 134
14  UIKit                           0x338c1a3c UIApplicationMain + 1132
15  MyAppName                       0x000845b8 main (main.m:16)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b9ccab2 tlv_initializer + 2
```

Please anybody have any idea to achieve my requirement.

Here is my code for adding and removing annotations.(When I get new location).

```
for(CSMapAnnotation *annotation in _mapView.annotations){

        if([annotation isEqual:annotationEnd]){

            [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotationEnd];

            annotationEnd = nil;
        }

    }
annotationEnd = [[CSMapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:[[pointsArray objectAtIndex:
([pointsArray count] - 1)] coordinate] annotationType:CSMapAnnotationTypeEnd title:@""];

[_mapView addAnnotation:annotationEnd];
```

Comment: Would be good to have some code to check exactly what you are doing, but the crash report implies you are changing an array whilst enumerating through it. (i.e. adding or removing an object whilst looping through it)

Comment: It looks like you are doing something wrong in a fast enumeration for loop (changing, enumerating non enumeratable items, weak v strong reference, few options) (for (xxxx in xxxx)). But you should post your own code

Comment: Thanks for your response lan L and William Falcon. I add my code above. Please check it once.